# General Purpose Smart Lock -- how to approach the need to turn this deadbolt?

Tags: doors, lock

I can't take apart this door or handle or lock mechanism. (I rent this apartment long term.)

How do I approach adding a smart lock to a door handle like this? The need is to go over this deadbolt knob and turn it.

[image]

Comment: replace the hardware with more common shapes.

Comment: @dandavis I understand that would be a path forward. I am a renter here long term and can't change the lock.

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica that's crucial information that belongs in the question, not as a comment after people make assumptions...

Comment: A quick web-search "electronic lock for existing deadbolt" seems to reveal some options. How to mount them may be an issue: a rental that won't let you change the hardware may have trouble letting you screw on the added lock mechanism. Maybe good doubleside or carpet tape?

Comment: @FreeMan The OP was updated early on. Sorry I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of smart devices designed for operating existing valves. Pretend your deadbolt thumb latch is a valve and install one of these types of devices.

[Here](https://www.emerson.com/en-us/catalog/topworx-pd) is one example that I found after a quick search. This one is designed for industrial use, so it may or may not meet your aesthetic requirements, but it's a possibility.

*NOTE: I have zero affiliation with the manufacturer or any of their retailers. It's simply the first one I managed to find that met the requirements.*

Answer (score 1):

(1) Buy another door without a door knob hole predrilled.

(2) Remove the existing door from its hinges and replace it with the new door.

(3) Buy a smart lock and drill your new door to match the existing strike plate with the smart lock.

(4) Install the smart lock and enjoy.

Comment: This ignores the note in the OP that I am renting and can't change stuff.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable answer, based on the _information provided in the question_. It's obviously not so good once the OP pipes up that this is a rental and replacement isn't an option.

Comment: @Jonesome Reinstate Monica, I was jesting at your expense. Apologies. In good faith, that lock looks proprietary, where I suspect that there's nothing standard about its interface to the door jamb. Unless the same manufacturer sells a "smart" replacement or retrofit, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a thumb turn that installs as a mortise cylinder. If do, you might be able to get a smart lock mechanism designed to install as a replacement for that.

Otherwise you are looking for something that can be clamped into the thumb turn. Some of the earliest smart locks were kludges of that sort, so there might still be one on the market. You would probably have to improve a way to mount the housing, since you can't do the usual thing of driving screws into the door.

Or you can hit the homebrew sites on the web and see if there's a build-your-own solution available.

I'm afraid this means you're going to have to spend some time searching the web. Doing that for you is out of scope.